# React.js cannot implement states

Tags: reactjs

Here's my code, I was implementing all I've learn about states and props but I seem to miss something out and don't know what.

I think I've made a mistake in parenthesis or something. Also my approach to this simple problem is different as I'm not following the React.org docs, should I refer that instead?

https://codepen.io/bradleyboy/pen/OPBpGw

```
class Item extends React.Component
{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

  this.state = {
    status: "pending"
  };

  this.toggleTask = this.toggleTask.bind(this);
  }

  toggleTask(){
    this.setState(state => {
      if (state.status === "pending")
        return {status: completed}
      else 
        return {status: pending}
    }
  );
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>{props.name}</h1>
        <p>{this.state.status}</p>
        <button onClick = {toggleTask}> Click me! </button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    return(<div>
      <Item name = "Work" />
      <Item name = "Play" />
    </div>);
  }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: You probably have an error in the `console` - `toggleTask is not a function`.. You need to refer to `this` like this: `onClick = {this.toggleTask}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not referring to your class method, do it as this

```
return(
  <div>
    <h1>{this.props.name}</h1> 
    <p>{this.state.status}</p>
    <button onClick = {this.toggleTask}> Click me! </button>
    </div>
);
```

**EDIT**

Change your toggleTask and use strings to set state as and also in class component use this.props instead of props

```
toggleTask() {
this.setState(state => {
  if (state.status === "pending") return { status: "completed" };
  else return { status: "pending" };
});
```

}

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-chebyshev-h48dd) to show you how its done

Hope it helps

Comment: I did the change, still I dont get any output :(

Comment: @levinsondsouza I have updated my answer with sandbox example, please check

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the other answer(s), you should use `this.value` and `this.toggleTask`. You could also use a simpler approach through the [Hooks api](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) like so:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function Item(props) {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState('pending');

  function toggleTask() {
    const newStatus = status === 'pending' ? 'completed' : 'pending';
    setStatus(newStatus);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      <p>{status}</p>
      <button onClick={toggleTask}> Click me! </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Application() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Item name="Work" />
      <Item name="Play" />
    </div>
  );
}

/*
  * Render the above component into the div#app
  */
ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('root'));`enter code here`
```

Also note that you're not importing `ReactDOM` which has the `render` method you're trying to use.